# How to install react-navigation to an ejected expo project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-eas

currently I ejected my Expo project because I am working with the Bluetooth Low Energy library, and when I try to install React Navigation, I am facing the error "Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent "RNSScreen" was not found". It's very frustrating, and I would appreciate your help.

I have tried the following steps, but I didn't get any results:

1.
I followed the steps in React Navigation documentation, but it failed.

2. I tried it on a non-ejected project, and it worked. Then I ejected my project and encountered the same error again. There may be an issue with the ejection process, and the library may not be usable.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the app? I mean if you are using ```EAS Build``` it should work.

Comment: @SizoDevelops If you mean restarting the project, then yes, I have done it many times.

Comment: No I meant running ```eas build --profile development --platform android``` or ```expo prebuild```

Comment: @SizoDevelops Thanks for your repply, I tried eas build --pfofile development --platform android command, but it's end up with error

 "Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information."

like this and i tried expo doctor and expo doctor --fix-dependencies but it also did not work.